# Python dateutil parser parses wrong number of seconds

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-dateutil

Python dateutil is parsing strings correctly except for the seconds component of the string.

```
In [1]: from dateutil import parser
In [2]: parser.parse("05/09/2016 16:04.18")
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 9, 16, 4, 10)
```

dateutil.parser is parsing 16:04.18 as 16 hours, 4 minutes, and **10 seconds**, when it should be **18 seconds**.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parser doesn't know how to interpret that last non-standard portion of the time. The `.` instead of a `:` throws it off. Try using `parser.parse("05.09/2016 16:04:18")` instead.

You could also try using the datetime module instead since it can be customized with a mask to handle any date and time format.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime("05/09/2016 16:04.18", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M.%S')
```

Comment: It looks like when you use a colon, dateutil.parser reads it as seconds, but when you use a period, dateutil.parser reads it as hundredths of a minute.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're right. It reads it as hundredths of a minute and then truncates the value.